# Is the last thing a person sees imprinted on their retina?

Tags: physiology, mortality

The scary stories told around the campfire often include people killed by a monstrous entity. Its image, imprinted on the victim's retina, drives the coroner out of their mind.

Has anyone ever researched that?

Comment: I was reading a book that described this as an "outdated superstition". This was in a historical novel set in 1895.

Comment: It's been researched as trope in fiction, see http://jv.gilead.org.il/evans/optogram.html

Comment: I thought this was tried and failed with the investigation into jack the ripper. With modern knowledge of how the eye works, what possible mechanism could be proposed? -1 for that and a lack of corroboration of notability.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The American College of Optometrists has [a page on this alleged phenomenon, called "optograms"](http://www.college-optometrists.org/en/knowledge-centre/museyeum/online_exhibitions/eye/optography.cfm). They claim that *with chemical fixatives and immediate extraction of the retina*, one can discern a rough image representing the last image exposed on the retina. This is vaguely plausible, since the formation of an image does induce chemical changes in the retina.

In the mid-17th Century, a Jesuit friar named Christopher Schiener did some experiments on frogs [[Ref](http://www.museumofoptography.net/Hackney_Empire_files/Hackney%20Micro%20copy.pdf)]; later [Wilhelm Kühne (a physiologist of some repute)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilhelm_K%C3%BChne) did [similar experiments on rabbits](http://www.museumofoptography.net/www.museumofoptography.net/People_%28Scientists%29/Entries/2011/8/15_Wilhelm_Kuhne.html).

The College go so far as to say:

> The one and only case of a 'Human Optogram' is therefore that of
>   Erhard Gustav Reif in November 1880....[H]e was executed by guillotine in the prison
>   yard in the small German town of Bruchsal. His left eye was extracted
>   within ten minutes of the sentence being carried out. Reif's optogram,
>   some 4mm in height, does not survive, merely a simple sketch drawing
>   taken from it.... It has a superficial resemblance to a
>   guillotine blade although the victim's eyes were bandaged seconds
>   before the blade fell. Possibly they are the steps he had to ascend
>   shortly beforehand.

In 1975 [a group of German scientists in Heidelberg reproduced the original rabbit research](http://www.escrs.org/milan2012/programme/poster-details.asp?id=13127). It seems that they were able to produce rough images, but concluded that the technique had no forensic or scientific value.

Comment: Some of the images made in 1975 are available in the [Encyclopedia of Optography](http://books.google.com.au/books?id=JxPRdlObfi0C&pg=PP4&lpg=PP4&dq=Encyclopedia+of+Optography++By+Derek+Ogbourne&source=bl&ots=JM84Z7goEz&sig=k2O-KS3NrrEsxi7rGs4jYj89U0c&hl=en&sa=X&ei=cPQJUOONIajWmAXK3fSbCg&ved=0CDQQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=Encyclopedia%20of%20Optography%20%20By%20Derek%20Ogbourne&f=false) (page 12-). They are hugely underwhelming - [Pareidolia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareidolia) seems a much more plausible explanation.

Comment: @Oddthinking Thanks for fixing the frog reference. It was Wilhelm Kühne who did the rabbit experiments.